# Customize the jquery UI dialog form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm new to jquery UI, and I want to use the jquery dialog form in my website.
So I have the following code that displays an icon:

```
<a href='' class='bt_green' id='dialog'><span class='bt_green_lft'></span><strong>Add user</strong><span class='bt_green_r'></span></a>
```

However,in the dialog form example in Jquery website, they use a button like so:

```
<button id="create-user">Create a user</button>
```

And the javascript code that triggers the dialog form:

```
$( "#create_user" )
        .button()
        .click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
```

I thought that by just replacing the #create_user by an id that I would add next to "bt_green" class would work but It doesn't work, and still shows a sort of grey button behind the icon that I want to make clickable to show the dialog form.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your Javascript:

```
$(".bt_green") 
    .button() 
    .click(function() { 
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" ); 
    });
```

Comment: I did this too, but I found the problem, I Have to delete the button().However, I encountered another problem, the dialog box shows for few seconds and disappear. I don't know why.

Comment: @peterburg I wonder if you have some other Javascript Code closing it... Without seeing your code, I cannot really help.